# Suggestion for Reference book to study positive operator

Tags: reference-request

I want to learn about positive operators, about their square root and some other properties of them. I have two books on functional analysis but they haven't discussed about them. They have discuss some basic operators like self adjoint, normal, unitary etc. Can you suggest some reference book. Thanks.

Comment: FA by Reed and Simon, Vol 1 is a good book.

Comment: Thank you Sir..I will go through it